# How to skip 1x times table in for-loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for i in arr:
    for c_item in arr:
      print(f'{i} X {c_item} = {i * c_item}')
```

In my code, how can I skip 1X times table in for-loop?

I know using the `range()` function will solve it, but I'm looking for another way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A trivial method is to check the value of `i` before printing anything:

```
if i > 1:
    print(f'{i} X {c_item} = {i * c_item}')
```

Alternatively you can define two arrays:

```
arr1 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

for i in arr1:
    for c_item in arr2:
        print(f'{i} X {c_item} = {i * c_item}')
```

For fun (and future reference) here is a one liner that prints the whole table:

```
print("\n".join(f"{i} x {j} = {i*j}" for i in range(2, 10) for j in range(1, 10)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also slice the list:

```py
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for i in arr[1:]:
    for c_item in arr:
      print(f'{i} X {c_item} = {i * c_item}')
```

`arr[1:]` creates a copy of the list excluding the first element at index 0.